# ASP.Net Core Web API Controller action with many parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have ASP.Net Core Web API Controller's method that returns `List<Car>` based on query parameters.

```
[HttpPost("cars")]
public async Task<List<Car>> GetCars([FromBody] CarParams par)
{
    //...
}
```

Parameters are grouped in record type `CarParams`. There are about 20 parameters:

```
public class CarParams
{
    public string EngineType { get; set; }
    public int WheelsCount { get; set; }
    /// ... 20 params
    public bool IsTruck { get; set; }
}
```

I need to change this method from POST to GET, because I want to use a server-side caching for such requests.

Should I create a controller's method with 20 params?

```
[HttpGet("cars")]
public async Task<List<Car>> GetCars(string engineType, 
                                      int wheelsCount, 
                                  /*...20 params?...*/
                                         bool isTruck)
{
    //...
}
```

If this is the case: Is there a way to automatically generate such a complex URL for a client-side app?

Comment: You are aware of the URL length limitation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can keep the model. Update the action's model binder so that it knows where to look for the model data.

Use `[FromQuery]` to specify the exact binding source you want to apply.

```
[HttpGet("cars")]
[Produces(typeof(List<Car>))]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCars([FromQuery] CarParams parameters) {

    //...

    return Ok(data);
}
```

Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: `[Produces(typeof(List<Car>))]` attribute required because return type of method is `Task<IActionResult>`? ASP.NET Core introduces `IActionResult<T>`, so this attribute will not be required anymore?

Comment: How request URL should look like for this controller, please provide example. Is there a way to generate URL with query params from given `CarParams` object?

Comment: I've found a `QueryBuilder` class.

Comment: Just for reference URL may look like following:
http://localhost:12345/api/controllerName/actionName?property1=value1&porp2=value

While Model Binding will map values to properties of parameter type.

Answer (score 1):

Just change `[FromBody]` attribute with `[FromUrl]`